# React component's onClick not rendered after npm run build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a React component:

```
class Control extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSaveFile = this.handleSaveFile.bind(this);
    this.handleExecFile = this.handleExecFile.bind(this);
  }

  handleSaveFile(e) {
    ...
  }

  handleExecFile(e) {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={this.props.name} className="Control" >
        <button onClick={this.handleSaveFile}>Save</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleExecFile}>Exec</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

After building the project with npm run build, the application displays correctly, but the "control" component HTML has been reduced to:

```
<div id="control" class="Control">
    <button>Save</button>
    <button>Exec</button>
</div>
```

In other words it appears as if the "onClick" has been optimized away.

I am uncertain why that would happen?

I am new to React.js and I am new to front-end development, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After working with the application a bit longer I see what is happening.

Indeed there is no "onClick" rendered in the HTML of the React component, but the component does actually respond to clicks. The onClick is just being registered in a different way by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

This correct behavior of our build tool. Check your javascript file. Your handlers are placed at the javascript bundle.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer @galkin, I appreciate it.